# Memory Management and Performance - Declaring properties or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, properties, automatic-ref-counting

I've faced this situation a few times but I still don't understand exactly what is the difference. Here is a situation: I have a `UITableViewController`with several `UITextFields`, right now, when `method` `textFieldDidEndEditing` gets called it gets the data from `textField` and saves to `database`. It is pretty simple since I have  a `tapGestureRecognizer`, so when user gets out of `textField` it gets the text and saves to `database`. It does that each time user enters a `textField`in the screen. This screen is for changing data, therefore, user might just need to change one `textField`, otherwise I would save it all at once to `database`, which is kind of my question.

Another approach would be to create `BOOL` `properties` for each `textField`, set it to true when `data`on that `textField`changes, and when user leaves the screen, check `textFields`that changed and `saveInBackground`to `database`. That would avoid sending network requests every `textField`change, and would connect to network only once. If user has a bad connection, this would be much better.

Now, I like to keep my code simple, and I am always concerned about setting a lot of `properties` and storying a lot of values. Basically, I get the idea that the more `properties` I write, more memory I use. Is that true? Anyway, what I am looking for is to obtain some opinions about this scenario and which of the two approaches would you prefer.

Thanks.

Comment: A few BOOL properties will use virtually no extra memory. You are worried about nothing. Avoiding needless network calls is FAR more important than saving half a dozen bytes of memory.

Comment: There will be like 20-30 `BOOL`properties in one `view`. I do agree with you about the network calls. I'm just worried because sometimes I have a lot of `properties` of different types.

Comment: 30 `BOOL` properties will add 30 bytes. That's it. Unless you plan to create thousands of instances (all in memory at once) of this view controller then you are worried over nothing. Don't worry about simple little properties like this.

Comment: It's just ugly code though. Why don't you store all the BOOLs in a dictionary that correlate to the textField object with the keys being the textField tags as strings and the values being a BOOL. Or something like that... Or, even better, make objects that consist of two properties, one being a reference to a textField tag and the other being a BOOL. 20-30 BOOLS will just make your code impossible to read and reuse later.